# How to extend Firebug's inspector feature?

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug, inspect-element

I have found out that Firebug for Firefox is an open source project and we can extend it.

By searching for documentaion about Firebug extension development I found the following website:

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/extending-firebug/

Unfortunately its petty old and doesn't have information for current versions (i.e. 2.0.x) of Firebug.

My goal is to extend Firebug's inspector feature.

So can anyone please tell where I can find an up-to-date guide for Firebug extension development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing Firebug 2 is broken once [e10s](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) is enabled by default in Firefox. That's why Firebug 3 (aka [Firebug.next](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next)) was recreated from scratch based on the built-in devtools.

Therefore it is recommended to base new developer extensions on the built-in devtools instead of the old Firebug 2 source.
A guide describing how to do that is [available at the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Adding_a_panel_to_the_toolbox). And there are also [example extensions in the Firebug repository on GitHub](https://github.com/firebug/devtools-extension-examples) as well as a [template extension created by one of the devtools developers](https://github.com/victorporof/Restartless-Template).

Comment: Wow I had no idea abou Firebug.next i loved firebug but since native came out i was using that, now firebug is based on native im going back baby!